# Per field rules in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a bunch of documents that contain a few fields each. How can I write rules that only apply to a specific field in each document?

For example, if my documents looked like this:

```
{
  "displayName": "John Doe", // read and write
  "accessLevel": 3 // read only
}
```

How could I make it so that you can

- Read display name and access level
- Write to the display name
- Not write to the access level

I've gone through a lot of videos and Firestore docs and haven't found anything that shows how you would exercise this per-field control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to make a field non-modifiable. You do that by checking in your rules that the value of the field is the same after the request as before it.

I have a simple helper function for this in my rules:

```
function isUnmodified(key) {
  return request.resource.data[key] == resource.data[key]
}
```

I then call this function from within my `write` (or `create` and `update`) rules:

```
  allow update: if isAdmin() || isUnmodified('name');
```

So in my example above, any admin (as determined by my `isAdmin` function) can modify the name field, but other users can't.

Comment: That's a clever way of checking for changes, I hadn't considered that. Thank you so much for your help!